# Is this sentence correct? "I'm working in a way that is unrelated to weekend and holidays."

Tags: expressions

Mainly I'm working in my home with my laptop, so I take day-off when I need it. When I want to explain this, I say

> I'm working in a way that is unrelated to weekend and holidays.

But I feel there is a more easy-to-understand expression.

How would you say if you were me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a native speaker but I googled and found the word **[flextime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flextime)**.

Judging by the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flextime), you can say

> I work flexible hours.

or

> I have a flexible working schedule.

If you want to somehow use the words "weekends" and "holidays" in the sentence, you might say

> I have no fixed weekends and holidays, and my working schedule is flexible. It is me who decides when to have a weekend or a holiday.

If you just say

> I have no fixed weekends and holidays.

... the listener might misinterpret that as "I have a very demanding job, and cannot be sure that I'll be off-work on a particular weekend or holiday".

---

If you have no boss, that is, if you are self-employed, you might say just that to explain why you have no rigid work schedule:

> I am self-employed, thus my working schedule is free and has no fixed weekends or holidays.
>
> I'm a freelancer, thus the terms "weekends" and "holidays" do not apply to my work routine. I work when I need to, and I take rest when I feel like it.

Comment: Another possibility is: _I don’t work a 9-to-5 job_, although that might be better for someone who works a swing shift than for someone with a flexible schedule.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence above is not grammatically incorrect although I agree it is not well constructed. If I were writing in a fairly formal tone I’d probably write something along the lines of any of the following sentences:

“I work no set hours and I am therefore able to schedule my days off without regard to weekends or weekdays.”

“Weekends and weekdays have no impact on my work schedule as I am able to either work or take a day off at my own discretion.”

“As I set my own work schedule, I am able to work or take days off without regard to a standard Monday to Friday working week.”

“The days on which I work are flexible and completely independent of whether it is a weekend or a weekday.”*

If I were writing to a friend or in a less formal way I’d simply say:

“I work or take a day off as it suits me, regardless of whether it’s a weekday or a weekend.”

Answer (score 1):

If your schedule never changes:

> I have a set schedule

If your work schedule can change, and is determined **by your employer** (like most jobs):

> I have a floating schedule

If your schedule can change, and is determined **by you**:

> I have a flexible schedule
>
> I work flexible hours